# How to truncate or drop entire neo4j graph?

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am mostly familiar with MySQL, if I wanted to truncate a table I would normally issue the command

```
TRUNCATE <table>
```

And to drop

```
DROP <table>
```

Now, on neo4j -- what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest equivalent is

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

The `DETACH` keyword causes relationships of the nodes to be deleted as well.

This doesn't work well on large graphs (~10M nodes+, depending on your RAM), because the transaction state is held in memory. But you can work around that by repeating following command, which deletes 1M nodes at a time:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
LIMIT 1000000
```

Comment: Note that usage of DETACH DELETE also deletes relationships, which is also added to the transaction. It usually works better in lower batch sizes. You can use `apoc.periodic.iterate()` to delete in batches, which can be easier to manage.